# How to redirect from web page to windows application?

Tags: c#, windows, adfs

I have MVC application where I'm authenticating user through the ADFS and send that details to the windows application to authentication. 
The steps i followed are:

1. Sending username and password to ADFS.
2. Receiving token from ADFS once user authenticated.
3. Validating Token

I want to transfer the token and user details to Desktop Application to authenticate Windows Application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC application and the desktop application are two different applications.

So you need two Relying Parties (RP) in ADFS.

Then with SSO, once you are logged into one you are logged into the other.

If you are using ADFS 4.0, the desktop application can use ADAL.

Similar to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/) for Azure AD.